# how many type of GC roots in hotspot JVM

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have searching from internet and found that different articles shows different version of GC roots types, what types of GC roots with Oracle HotSpot JVM? I did not found any official docs talk about the type of HotSpot GC roots.

[This article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-gc-roots) did not contains some trust link or source:

the main types of GC Roots:

- Class: Classes loaded by a system class loader;
- contains references to static variables as well
- Stack Local: Local variables and parameters to methods stored on the local stack
- Active Java Threads: All active Java threads
- JNI References: Native code Java objects created for JNI calls; contains local variables, parameters to JNI methods, and global
  JNI references Additionally

there are a few more possible types of GC Roots:

> Objects used as monitors for synchronization Specific objects defined
> by the JVM implementation that are not garbage collected for its
> purpose. That might contain important exception classes, system class
> loaders, or custom class loaders